# Cannot locate Apache .conf file

Tags: linux, apache

I have an Apache server running,

`httpd -v` produces

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 13 2015 23:45:37
```

But, I can't seem to find any directories with the name Apache in them. `Running ps -ef | grep apache` results in

```
user1 16741 30600  0 15:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep apache
```

instead of showing the path for a directory it comes up with 'grep apache'.

Comment: `ps` lists processes, not directories...

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: @larsks `Linux version 3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-60007) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using Red Hat.  The Apache configuration files are in `/etc/httpd`, and the name of the Apache process, if it is running, is `httpd`.